# Android ListView: overriding causes scrolling do not executed

Tags: android, listview, scroll, overriding

I want to know if user is scrolling up or down.
I have began to override the `OnGestureListener.onScroll()` method and set my `GestureDetector` for the `ListView`.

```
public class ContactList extends ListView {

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public ContactList(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public ContactList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }

    public ContactList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent firstEvent, MotionEvent secondEvent, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                Log.d("tag", "onScroll "+firstEvent.getAction());
                Log.d("tag", "onScroll "+secondEvent.getAction());
                return true;

            };
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Debugging I noticed that it passes from onTouchEvent() but not from onScroll() and the scroll is not perfomed anymore by the `ListView`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried calling `super.onTouchEvent(event)` in your `onTouchEvent` method?

**Edit** - I think you want to return `false` as well in your `onScroll` method.

Then your `onTouchEvent` method should be:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Returning `false` in `onScroll()` is declaring event not consumed, so `onTouchEvent()` can forward event to superclass. It works. Thank you very much! :)